# Cell references in formulas keep moving with old data in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

When I update Excel to the latest figures my formulas keep moving with the old data. I have already tried using absolute and or relative references like $A$1, $A1, A$1, and A1. I've also tried using the protect feature, with no luck. Can anyone help with this? Thus far I've just had to lose half a day changing cell references back and macros may or may not damage the sheet.

Comment: See [How to Autofill Excel cells relatively with absolute formulas](https://superuser.com/questions/1518009/how-to-autofill-excel-cells-relatively-with-absolute-formulas?noredirect=1#comment2297953_1518009).

Answer (score 1):

One way to prevent the formulas from being altered as you alter the data is using [indirect addressing](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/indirect.htm) Basically, if you have this formula

```
=SUM(A1:A10)
```

it will be altered when you copy/paste the referenced cells. To prevent this, you can replace it by

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A1:A10"))
```

Once you specify your range as a string, Excel will not be able to track it back to the referenced cells anymore.